# SVG: Can I make an outer glow with a gradient?

Tags: svg, gradient, filter, composition, blending

I've seen a million tutorials to make outer glow effects using some combination of `feGaussianBlur`, `feFlood` and dilating either SourceGraphic or SourceAlpha. They work pretty well but aren't exactly what I need.

I've been trying to find a way (as well as experimenting on my own, unsuccessfully) for a way to make an outer glow effect colored with a linear gradient. Is this possible in SVG? I've tried using `feImage` but either I'm doing it wrong or it just can't be done.

Comment: Since you have  outlined methods that dont  work exactly as you want and not described what you exactly want answer is: No. Otherwise it  would be yes.

Comment: Can you give more details on the code that you are working on? Maybe share an example? Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630008/how-can-i-create-a-glow-around-a-rectangle-with-svg) may relate to your question.

Comment: I want an outer glow around a path but I want that glow to be colored according to a lineal gradient, as opposed to just a solid color. Is this possible? I thought the initial description was clear but I guess not.

Comment: I want a glow similar to what @Socowi answered. I managed to get it working finally thanks to someone in #svg; Seems my main problem was I needed to put the gradients and gradient rectangle in the defs at the top.

Comment: Here's the working example of what I was trying to do, for reference to anybody who might have the same issue in the future: https://jsfiddle.net/litenstein/fxba57yj/44/

Comment: @GregorioLitenstein Please post you solution as an answer and accept it so that the question can be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of a coding problem and the question already has an answer over on another SE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630008/how-can-i-create-a-glow-around-a-rectangle-with-svg

Comment: @Luciano that question was different from mine and did not answer my problem (in fact, I made this question AFTER reading that one and its answers). The difference is I wanted a my glow to not be a solid color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted a glow similar to what @Socowi originally posted:

[image: Version 1] [image: Version 2]

I managed to get it working finally thanks to someone in #svg; Seems my main problem was I needed to put the gradients and gradient rectangle in the `defs` at the top.

Here's the working example, for reference to anybody who might have the same issue in the future:

```
<svg id="glowy" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

    <defs>      <!-- We set the filter effect area to be really big to guarantee we see it all... -->
        <linearGradient id='lgrad' x1='50%' y1='100%' x2='50%' y2='0%' > 
    <stop offset='0%' style='stop-color:rgb(181,7,7);stop-opacity:1' />
    <stop offset='12%' style='stop-color:rgb(250,141,95);stop-opacity:1' />
    <stop offset='25%' style='stop-color:rgb(247,176,94);stop-opacity:1' />
    <stop offset='37%' style='stop-color:rgb(255,231,191);stop-opacity:1' />
    <stop offset='50%' style='stop-color:rgb(255,253,209);stop-opacity:1' />
    <stop offset='67%' style='stop-color:rgb(255,231,191);stop-opacity:1' />
    <stop offset='75%' style='stop-color:rgb(247,176,94);stop-opacity:1' />
    <stop offset='87%' style='stop-color:rgb(250,141,95);stop-opacity:1' />
    <stop offset='100%' style='stop-color:rgb(181,7,7);stop-opacity:1' />
</linearGradient> 

    <rect width='105%' height='80%'  y='10%' x='-5%' fill='url(#lgrad)' id='gradientRect'></rect>
  <filter  id='red-orangeGlow' width='150%' height='150%' x='-25%' y='-25%'>
    <!--     Thicken out the original shape     -->
    <feMorphology  in='SourceAlpha' operator='dilate' radius='3.5' result='thickenR'></feMorphology>
 <feGaussianBlur  in='thickenR' result='blurredR' stdDeviation='10'></feGaussianBlur> 
 <feFlood result='floodR' flood-color='#ffffff'/>
 <feComposite in='floodR' in2='blurredR' operator='in' result='filledBlur'/>
 <feImage xlink:href="#gradientRect" result="gRectangle"/>
<feComposite  in='gRectangle' in2='filledBlur' operator='in' result='finalBlur'/>

    <feMerge>           
         <feMergeNode  in='finalBlur'></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode  in='SourceGraphic'></feMergeNode>
    <!--        <feMergeNode  in='softGlow_coloredO'></feMergeNode>  -->
    </feMerge>
</filter>

    </defs>

    <g transform="translate(20,20)">
        <rect x="0" y="0"  width="140" height="140" rx="5" ry="5" style="fill: #555555; filter:url(#red-orangeGlow)"/>
        </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Images from my deleted answer/comment for future reference: [version 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS65l.png), [version 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSxkW.png). Please include images and code directly into your answer so that it is self-contained.

Comment: I'm confused. Is this the answer to your own question? If so can you expand on the explanation and keep the link? Please take a look at [answer].

Comment: @Luciano I had originally posted that I found the solution as a comment and then somebody told me to answer it so the question could eventually be closed as answered. I've added all the relevant pieces now.

Comment: Does not work in Firefox (because it does not support using xlink:href with an internal object in an feImage).